# Do Vedas contain scientifically inaccurate verses?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, yajur-veda, science

**Sky can fall on Earth:**

**Rig Veda II.17.5**

> Fast (Indra) upheld the earth that nourisheth all life, and stayed the
>   **heaven from falling by his wondrous skill**.

**Cooked articles causes rain:**

**Yajur Veda III.49**

> The oblation full of cooked articles put into the fire, goes up to the
>   sky. And returns there from full of rain.”

**Yajur Veda II.16**

> ”We perform the yajna for Vasus, Rudras and Adityas…The desired
>   oblation (Ahuti) reaches the space, comes in contact with air and the
>   light of that sun. It thence brings down rain for us…”

**Earth has ends:**

**Rig Veda X.58.3**

> Thy spirit, that went far away, away to the **four-cornered earth**, We
>   cause to come to thee again that thou mayst live and sojourn here.

**Earth is flat:**

**Rig Veda III.6.5**

> Great are the deeds of thee, the Great, O Agni: thou by thy power hast
>   **spread out earth and heaven.**

Comment: First of all you're asking about too many verses in a single question, and second of all scientific speculation is not allowed here.  If you want to post a question about a single verse and ask about what that verse means, without asking how it comports with modern science, that may be more acceptable.

Comment: four-cornered earth: I would love to see them. Mr. Keshav, he asked the question that they have scientific error or not, just answer that. Why cannot anyone ask these kind of questions, any reason?

Comment: @AliAdravi four-cornered does not mean a 4-sided polygon. Does your city have north,south, east, west direction? does your house? And even more importantly, a lot is lost in translation when vedic hymns are translated into pale english.

Comment: As i have already told **DONT read Griffith, Whitney translations** of the Vedas.They are just summary translations, they are not word to word translations. For numerous mantras their translations are misleading and can be used to show Vedas in bad light.

Comment: @Rickross Arya Samaj translation too?

Comment: @Hindu I have not read their translations yet but Griffith, Whitney's translation should be shunned.

Answer (score 3):

Vedas are very poetic and the same words could mean very different things in different contexts. I will try to answer some of the points made here.

> Cooked articles causes rain:

The 'cooked articles causing rain' is not very unusual and could mean convection. For example, acid rain is caused as an after-effect of burning coal. If someone mentions that the fumes caused by burning coal goes up and precipitates and comes down as rain, it's quite scientific. Likewise convection rainfall cycle does mention that water vapor rises, cools down into clouds and then due to pressure differences precipitates, so the sun is definitely involved. So the fact that cooked food burning would affect the quality of rainfall is not unscientific.

> Earth has ends

The fact that boundaries of the earth have been measured means that the earth has bounds and ends. It's your interpretation that a boundary is two dimensional. And of course, the earth is bounded, it's not endless as your unscientific mind thinks.

> Earth is Flat

The word 'spread out' earth and heaven can mean many many things. It doesn't necessarily mean that the Earth is flat.

In short, it would be useful to paste the exact Sanskrit verses along with your question so that we can eliminate the (European etc) interpretation which is usually poetic and try to derive a more accurate meaning.